# Unable to access the routes of a dockerized flask application from a web server

Tags: python, docker, flask, deployment, http-status-code-404

I have a flask application that runs perfectly in localhost even with docker.
But as soon as I deploy it, it doesn't work anymore.
I have a 404 errorcin the back, and the browser answers with:

> Not Found The requested URL was not found on the server. If you
> entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

When I curl localhost:5010/helloworld from my server, I get an empty answer.. I don't know why, but it seems that the flask server doesn't restart:

```
WARNING:root:no config found for parameter None default mode debug loaded
WARNING:flask_cors.core:Unknown option passed to Flask-CORS: headers
WARNING:flask_cors.core:Unknown option passed to Flask-CORS: headers
 * Serving Flask app "application" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
INFO:werkzeug: * Running on https://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:werkzeug: * Restarting with stat
WARNING:root:no config found for parameter None default mode debug loaded
WARNING:flask_cors.core:Unknown option passed to Flask-CORS: headers
WARNING:flask_cors.core:Unknown option passed to Flask-CORS: headers
WARNING:werkzeug: * Debugger is active!
INFO:werkzeug: * Debugger PIN: 899-121-971
```

run.py:

```
from application import create_app, db
import sys

from OpenSSL import SSL
context = SSL.Context(SSL.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
context.use_privatekey_file('./ssl/server.key')
context.use_certificate_file('./ssl/server.crt')

# we set the app default  value is debug 
appStartingMode= None
if(len (sys.argv) >1):
    appStartingMode= sys.argv[1]

app = create_app(appStartingMode)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.debug = True
    app.use_reloader = True
    app.run(host=app.config['FLASK_HOST'], port=app.config['FLASK_PORT'],ssl_context = context)
```

The Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9.1

EXPOSE 5000

# Install pip requirements
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN python -m pip install -r requirements.txt

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

# Switching to a non-root user, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python-user-rights
RUN useradd appuser && chown -R appuser /app
USER appuser

# During debugging, this entry point will be overridden. For more information, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python-debug
CMD [ "python", "./run.py" ]
```

An extract of the docker-compose.yml:

```
  bel-backend:
    container_name: bel-backend
    env_file: database-variables.env
    build:
      context: /home/ubuntu/sob/sob-2020-back-end
    ports:
      - 5010:5000
    depends_on :
      - mysql-server
```

And the route I try to access:

```
@app.route('/helloworld', methods=['GET'])
def helloWorld():
    print("ok")
    return 'Hello World !'
```

By typing: https://ipofthemachine:5010/helloworld
even if the https crosses out because I have to renew my certificate.
Any ideas?

[EDIT]

Better if I share the config.py:

```
from os import environ, path
from dotenv import load_dotenv

basedir = path.abspath(path.dirname(__file__))
load_dotenv(path.join(basedir, '.env'))

class Config:
    """Base config."""
    SECRET_KEY = environ.get('SECRET_KEY')
    '''
    SESSION_COOKIE_NAME = environ.get('SESSION_COOKIE_NAME')
    STATIC_FOLDER = 'static'
    TEMPLATES_FOLDER = 'templates'
    '''

class DebugConfig(Config):
    # General Flask Config
    FLASK_ENV = 'development'
    DEBUG = False
    #TESTING = True
    FLASK_APP = 'run.py'
    FLASK_PORT=5000
    FLASK_HOST='0.0.0.0'


    # Database
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = environ.get('SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI')
    SQLALCHEMY_ECHO = False
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False
```

Comment: What FLASK_HOST you have given in you config file?

Answer (score 0):

Add to the bottom of your routes script

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

Comment: I updated my post: I put my config.py. Thanks for your answer. I'm already doing that.

Comment: have you tried to access it via the container name ie:  bel-backend:5010/helloworld

Comment: When i do that from the server itself i get:
`curl: (6) Could not resolve host: bel-backend`
When i do `>curl localhost:5010/helloworld` I get the following:
`curl: (52) Empty reply from server`

Comment: Have you tried running it without ssl just to see if it is in fact an issue with the certs?

Comment: I removed `ssl_context = context` from the run.py and tried again to curl from the server itself, and I got the same result

Comment: have you tried just leaving it at the same port ie. 5000:5000

Comment: yes but didn't work... i don't know if you see my edit but the `INFO:werkzeug: * Running on https://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)` doesn't show up in the logs but it does in localshost... don't know if it can help

Comment: try hard coding the app.run() parameters to rule out there is not a problem loading the config

Comment: I answered to you with a new answer since it was beginning to be large here...

Answer (score 0):

@Dunski I answer because the main post is gonna be long if I edit it..

So I did what you said: I hard-coded the app.run. Now, I have:

```
appStartingMode= None
if(len (sys.argv) >1):
    appStartingMode= sys.argv[1]

app = create_app(appStartingMode)
```

The Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9.1

EXPOSE 5000
# Install pip requirements
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN python -m pip install -r requirements.txt

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

# Switching to a non-root user, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python-user-rights
RUN useradd appuser && chown -R appuser /app
USER appuser

# During debugging, this entry point will be overridden. For more information, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python-debug
CMD ["flask", "run", "-host", "0.0.0.0", "-port", "5000"]
```

And the .env file I read in the docker-compose:

```
user=root                                                                    
password=*****                                                           
host=mysql                                                                 
port=3306                                                                   
database=bel_2020_db                                                        
                                                                 
SECRET_KEY=secret                                                          
FLASK_APP=run.py                                                           
FLASK_ENV=development                                                      
FLASK_DEBUG=0                                                               
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI=mysql://${user}:${password}@${host}:${port}/${database
}?charset=utf8mb4&binary&binary_prefix=true                                   
SQLALCHEMY_ECHO=0                                                             
SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS=0
```

Now, I tried to curl the docker with his ip adress from the server itself... Didn't work!!!!! Everything works on localhost... I'm starting to lose hope.
The server DO receive the request, but returns a 404...

Comment: Dont lose hope will will get it sorted. I need to go out and do a few things but I will set it up myself on my linux vm later and I should see what the problem is then

Comment: Hi Dunski,
I hope you had a good christmas vacation.
I could make it works. I'm ashamed to say it: I was running the command docker up without build. So obviously I was still working on the same version, and my error persisted. Now it's fixed:
- I can reach my helloworld route. According to previous topics, I think that WE HAVE TO run flask with FLASK CLI to make it work. Don't ask me why...
- However, I still cannot connect flask to my database...

Comment: haha. well at least you got it working. Had a lovely Christmas thanks